# 'public MyDBAdapter open()' What does 'open()' means after MyDBAdapter?

Tags: java, android

What does 'open()' means after MyDBAdapter? MyDBAdapter is class name.

```
public MyDBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open` is the method name. The fragment you pasted defines a public method called `open` which takes no arguments (there's nothing listed between the parentheses) which returns an instance of `MyDBAdapter` and may throw a `SQLException`.

You may want to have a look at the tutorial on method declaration: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: yea, but, why i needed to write MyDBAdapter before?
public open() throws SQLException { - correct?

Comment: That's the return type. If you didn't want to return anything you would use `public void open()...` (and then remove the `return this;`)

Comment: ^_^ yea, yea, i see =) Oh, my stupid brain =) i'll have to go sleep for a bit =) thx.